# What is the name of a thing that can be present or absent?

Tags: single-word-requests

It is an arbitrary, abstract thing. Its only interesting quality is that it can be present or absent. I'd settle for a thing that exists or doesn't exist, is here or not here, etc. I'm just after a single word to describe this thing.

Comment: *Binary* -- it's only known characteristic is being binary.

Comment: how about item? entity?

Comment: Very difficult to answer this- every single thing can be either present or absent, exist or not exist, therefore every single thing has this quality. I think you need to expand and clarify.

Comment: Yes, please do clarify. The answers so far rather beautifully demonstrate that nobody has the slightest idea what on Earth you are even talking about.

Comment: I've accepted "Presence", because its the answer we managed to come up with ourselves. Its sort of obvious really when I used "present" as one of the states in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, question seemed too vague, but seriously, that was it. "Presence" works, as in the sentence "There is a presence here". It says nothing about that thing other than it being here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact of something being either absent or present is called its ***presence***.

<sub>From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presence) :</sub>

> The fact or condition of being present

---

If you are interested in

> for a thing that exists or doesn't exist

you may talk about its ***reality***.

<sub>From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reality)</sub>

> The state of being actual or real.

Answer (score 2):

As Sheldon Cooper would shout:

> **[Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Being** : the state or quality of having existence

**Beingness** : the state or fact of existing

**Existence** : the fact or state of existing

**Existability** : the possibility that something can exist

**So the quality of Existing, or not Existing, is Existability**.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/existability

Example usage:

The **Existability** of happiness in rocks is in the negative. [[Meaning : Rocks are devoid of happiness]]

The **Existability** of hardness in rocks is in the positive. [[Meaning : Rocks may or may not have the attribute of hardness. Some rocks are hard, while some are soft]]

So whether some quality can be present (or not) is expressed by **Existability**.

Answer (score 1):

When we speak about an assumed thing, that may or may not exist, we use 'hypothetical'

**hypothetical** on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hypothetical)

> Logic.
>
> (of a proposition) highly conjectural; not well supported by
> available evidence.
>
> (of a proposition or syllogism) conditional.

Usage examples on [yourdictionary.com](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/hypothetical)